# Can I use python-couchdb from behind a proxy?

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm trying to connect to a couchdb server on another machine.  I need to use my proxy-settings in order to connect.

When I run the following from command-line:

```
curl -x "localhost:3128" http://<couchdb url>:<port>
```

I get back the successful response:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.2.0"}
```

When I try to connect via python-couchdb

```
couch = Server('http://<couchdb url>:<port>')
db = couch['db_name']
```

I get the error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I can't figure out how to tell python-couchdb about the proxy settings.  Any advice?

Comment: It seems that this is a known, open issue of couch-db: it does not support proxies... see http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/issues/detail?id=135

Comment: Hm, ok.  Doesn't seem like it will be fixed in the near future (given when that was identified).  Do you know if there's a workaround or another library that might work instead?

Comment: It was supposed to be a simple matter of changing the `http_proxy` environment variable to be the proxy's address. However, looking at couchdb-python's source code (which uses httplib), this probably won't work. Try using Couchdbkit at http://couchdbkit.org/ , and set the aforementioned environment variable. Not sure it will work though...

Comment: Looking into it.  Documentation not totally clear on couchdbkit either.  Will report if it works.

Comment: I still haven't figured this out.  If anyone has done this before, I would be very curious to know how!